Logging multiple model metrics runs to the same plot in MLFlow
I’m doing a grid search optimization on model parameters and logging the loss to MLFlow using
Mlflow.log_metric(f“{run_number}_Loss”, returns, iteration)

But for every new run, I get a different plot in the MLFlow UI.
Is there a way to log to the same plot multiple times, maybe different colors, and add a legend to be able to compare different runs easily?
